# Displace adds an extra noise

Tags: modifiers

Anybody knows if I can limit the noise generate by displace modifier? On my test I have used a picture like following.

[image]

But the results are like this:
[image]
There seems to be unexpected noise on the edges. The problem comes worst when I try to subdivide the plane over 100 times. Subdividing I'm using to make smooth edges.

Here is a screen capture from original file showing that there were only two colors used on the edges. The yellow rectangle on blender picture shows the place where this part has been taken when the original image has been zoomed in 600%.
[image]

Comment: Those look lot like jpeg jaggies, was your displacement map ever a jpeg?

Comment: Yes it is, only a jpeg..

So basically what you are saying, I should have subdivided double (at least) compared to the image resolution to having clear edges?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need displacement?

For a shape like this it would be a lot easier to create clean geometry and with a lot less vertices.

Or trace the shape as path in a vector drawing program (inkscape, illustrator, etc) and save as SVG to import back to blender.

Diagonal lines will always be jagged in raster formats (and in this case you see clearly how compression creates other artifacts).

Comment: This was just an example. I have a logo picture, and that I try to make it to 3D model and I though displacement would be the easiest way to do it. Then I hit to the noise issue, and I wonder if simple pictures do have the same issue. So now I'm here :)

Comment: For logos use SVGs Displacement, as you experienced, will never give you straight lines, and you need many subdivisions for a clean displacement. On top of that the quality will always be determined by the size, resolution, compression and bit depth of the image.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your alternative idea. The logo is unfortunately on jpeg only. But let see how Inkscape can help me with this :)

Thanks and have a great day !